# Why does my app return NaN as the speed in my gps based app

Tags: windows-phone-7, gps

I am writing an app for Windows Phone 7 that uses the GPS to track how far and how fast the user is going. Using the Haversine formula according to Dr. Math.            [http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51879.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20171224103604/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51879.html) I can figure out how far this device has moved since the GPS was started. I am trying to display the speed that the user is traveling in a textblock in miles per hour by using this code here This code is fired when the position is changed.

```
tblSpeed.Text == (((watcher.Position.Location.Speed * 60) * 60) / 1609.344).ToString()
```

When I run the app in the emulator and using the GPS emulator recipe found on the WP7 blog I only get 'NaN' in my speed text block. I have a timer that is timing how long the gps has been tracking and I have tried this code there too with the same result. Any ideas on what I could do to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the GPS Recipe doesn't transmit the speed properly. However, check a comment by Morten Nielsen on the [blog page](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/01/28/windows-phone-gps-emulator.aspx#comments) as he explains how to manually calculate the speed.